# How do I start scrolling a left column and then automatically start scrolling the right column after reaching the bottom of the left column?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have the following scenario. Section with content. Another section below with two divs, column left and column right. Then another section with more content.

I need to scroll down through the first section. Upon reaching the next section, I need the left column to start scrolling. Upon reaching the end of the left column the right column will start scrolling. Upon reaching the bottom of the right column both the left and the right column with move up the screen at the same time allowing the content below to come into view.

I have them so that they are scrollable independantly

```
<section>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</section>

<section>
<div class='column-left'>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>

<div class='column-right'>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
</section>

<section>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</section>

<section>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</section>

<section>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</section>
```

Here's what I've got. This allows them to scroll independantly but I'm not sure how to achieve the scrolling the way I've describe above. Any help is appreciated.

```
  .column-left {
    width: 74%;
    max-height: 1250px;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 2rem;
    background-color: #fff;

  }
  .column-left::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }

  .column-left:hover{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
  }

  .column-right {
    width: 26%;
    max-height: 1250px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    scrollbar-width: none;
    float: right;
    padding: 0rem 3rem 6rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #00185a;
    color: #fff;
  }
  .column-right::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none; 
  }
  .column-right img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 396px;
  }
```